# ReportNG report display Blank Gray Box

Tags: selenium, testng, reportng

I have an Issue with ReportNG, It's working fine and generated 'index.html' under surefire-reports after every executions.

But when I tried to send that report as an email attachment, and open that attachment 'index.html' for view the report

Report displayed as Gray Empty Box attached[Empty ReportNG report](https://i.stack.imgur.com/diX80.jpg)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you only sent index.html file in email? it need other supporting file right? All these files required to display correctly.

So better to have total output folder.. or need to find what are supporting files required for index.hml file and need attach all.

Comment: Yes, Murali your are right, I have done the same mistake, only import and send single html file due to which it broke all the <html> links corresponding to Report.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue but when I executed the command below in the script console it worked. Please try:

```
System.setProperty("hudson.model.DirectoryBrowserSupport.CSP", " ")
```